# Why was my edit rejected and can I do anything about it?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I was wondering why my edit [7705892](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7705892) on stack overflow was rejected.  It improves the grammar and moves code from a comment, which should of been in the original post.  Both of these things are called out in the [When Should I Edit Posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) rules.  The descriptions for the rejections don't make any sense, the final reviewer claimed that it harmed readability, which I completely don't understand.

Comment: Mmm, If I were reviewing that, I would have approved it. Maybe just editing some grammar sounded too trivial to the reviewers. This specially happens when the post does look like a horrible text message, but is understandable. If your edit doesn't make it more understandable for anyone, then they have a reason to reject it.

Answer (score 4):

I would also reject this. You broke the iron rule: **do not change code in other user's post**.

You totally changed the code, adding your own code as well. This alone justifies rejecting the edit, no matter what else you changed in the post.

Even if the author of the post added that code as a comment, it's his/her place to edit the post and add that code so ask in a comment reply "please add this into your post", or leave this to 2K user to do if the author is not responding after a while.

Also, changing "Please advice !" to "Please help!" is totally meaningless, it's just noise and should be removed anyway.

Also, the rejection descriptions make total sense.

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post

True: as I said above, you should ask the author of the post to make such an edit.

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read

True: this one refers to changing "advice" to "help".

Last but not least: when you didn't touch code and only improved a post, [it went through smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7705382).

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, I wasn't aware that I should of made a comment  instead of moving the code.

Comment: Well, now you know. :)